# Optimized Table and now Unable to Enter Longtext values

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes

I optimized my table with an option in phpmyadmin as it was flashing below. I was using `LONGTEXT` type for my column `file_data`. Now, for some reason, huge values are not being entered into this column. It gives `NULL`. What can I do and do I have to change the data type to `ENUM` as suggested by **propose table structure**?

Thanks,
JJ

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to insert long text in the field.
The only option is to make (change it back) field as text field.

Please run following SQL, (replace the table name in SQL)

ALTER TABLE `<<your table name>>` CHANGE `file_data` `file_data` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ;